# detect completely browser closed in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, browser, polymer

I am working on a project using polymer 3  where I want to destroy/clear a cookie and log out the user from the website. Destroying or clearing cookie is not an issue but I am just not able to detect when the browser closes.

So far I have tried:

```
    window.onbeforeunload
```

from the JavaScript end and for php have tried this:

```
    session_set_cookie_params(0);
```

but none are working. Any help would be really appreciable.
I can use `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()` function but it's not fulfilling my requirement.

Plz don't suggest any jQuery suggestion.

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing It basically says: "You can only detect when the page is unloaded, not when the window is closed."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect browser or tab closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing)

Comment: please read my question first

Comment: dear @Justin Schwimmer, i tried all the stackoveflow suggestion for couple of hours.
before answer u should really check my question properly. dont ans any que until u become certain about it.

Comment: Sounds like you wanna detect when a browser is closed? Wait you said: "i just not able to detect browser close" - now I'm certain about it! Plus the title...

Comment: yes thats what i want

Comment: you don't get the information you want, because it's none of your buisness. All the browser will tell you is wether your page is closing. Wether this is because someone closed the tab, or the entire browser, is not your buisness. The same way that it is not your buisness what other tabs are open in the browser.

Comment: *"I want to destroy/clear a cookie and log out the user from the website"* the use a session cookie, and declare a Session as terminated after let's say 30 minutes of inactivity. And if it's the kind of website where you often have long periods of inactivity by the user, then mybe you want to implement a ping every 5 minutes, just to tell the server "I'm still here"

Comment: I've read your question that's why I flagged it as a duplicate. You want to use ajax on your browser close event which you can find in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing#answer-44057659

Comment: @SaadSuri i definitely check out those que and ans when i  didnt get anything then i post a que here. i really dont wannt to disturb other with a bad que and also harm my reputation.
i also mention what i tried so far

Comment: @sayalok Try session cookies http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Comment: @misorude i consider it and that is why i asked for help here.

Comment: @Znaneswar tried this one also before even posting que here

Answer (score 0):

Use [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage). It Works propably exactly as you want. Whenever user close browser, everything in sessionStorage is removed. Be aware that it works only when user completely close browser. Not only a tab.

Answer (score 0):

I would go the other way around. If the user arrives to the page for the first time, log out the user. You can easily do that by checking if a certain variable is set or not, and then set it whenever the user logs in.